# RuntimeError: input must have 3 dimensions, got 2 RNN in pytorch

Tags: nlp, pytorch

I have a Seq2Seq model with the following dataloader:

```
inp_fields = Field(sequential = False, use_vocab = True, tokenize = tokenize_text, lower = False, fix_length=100, init_token="<sos>", eos_token="<eos>")
out_fields = Field(sequential = True, use_vocab = True, tokenize = tokenize_text, lower = False, fix_length=100, init_token="<sos>", eos_token="<eos>")

train_data, test_data = TabularDataset.splits(path='', train = 'train.json', test = 'test.json', format='json', fields = {'inputs':('text', inp_fields), 'outputs':('label', out_fields)})

train_itr, test_itr = BucketIterator.splits((train_data, test_data), batch_size=32, device = device, sort_key = lambda x: len(x.text),
    sort_within_batch=True)
```

I am getting an error in the dimensions for the batch in the encoder:

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, emb_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.hid_dim = hid_dim
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_dim, emb_dim)
        
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(emb_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout = dropout)
        
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
    def forward(self, src):
        
        embedded = self.dropout(self.embedding(src))
        
        outputs, (hidden, cell) = self.rnn(embedded)
        
        
        return hidden, cell
```

The error is:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-632d269d9be5> in <module>()
     13     start_time = time.time()
     14 
---> 15     train_loss = train(model, train_itr, optimizer, criterion, CLIP)
     16     valid_loss = evaluate(model, test_itr, criterion)
     17     test_loss_l.append(valid_loss)

8 frames
<ipython-input-64-ed5f7e3d195a> in train(model, iterator, optimizer, criterion, clip)
     14         optimizer.zero_grad()
     15 
---> 16         output = model(src, trg)
     17 
     18         #trg = [trg len, batch size]

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-48-9072bb990be1> in forward(self, src, trg, teacher_forcing_ratio)
     25 
     26         #last hidden state of the encoder is used as the initial hidden state of the decoder
---> 27         hidden, cell = self.encoder(src)
     28 
     29         #first input to the decoder is the <sos> tokens

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-46-e4c4353adb6d> in forward(self, src)
     20         #embedded = [src len, batch size, emb dim]
     21 
---> 22         outputs, (hidden, cell) = self.rnn(embedded)
     23 
     24         #outputs = [src len, batch size, hid dim * n directions]

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in forward(self, input, hx)
    675             hx = self.permute_hidden(hx, sorted_indices)
    676 
--> 677         self.check_forward_args(input, hx, batch_sizes)
    678         if batch_sizes is None:
    679             result = _VF.lstm(input, hx, self._flat_weights, self.bias, self.num_layers,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in check_forward_args(self, input, hidden, batch_sizes)
    618                            batch_sizes: Optional[Tensor],
    619                            ):
--> 620         self.check_input(input, batch_sizes)
    621         self.check_hidden_size(hidden[0], self.get_expected_hidden_size(input, batch_sizes),
    622                                'Expected hidden[0] size {}, got {}')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in check_input(self, input, batch_sizes)
    201             raise RuntimeError(
    202                 'input must have {} dimensions, got {}'.format(
--> 203                     expected_input_dim, input.dim()))
    204         if self.input_size != input.size(-1):
    205             raise RuntimeError(

RuntimeError: input must have 3 dimensions, got 2
```

This error occurred when I appended  and  tags to my input fields. I guess that the 3 required dimensions are src len, batch size, emb dim.
What is wrong here? What are the dimensions that are missing?

Comment: Have you checked the shape of `embedded` tensor? `self.rnn(...)` is causing this error and my best guess is that you're providing the wrong shape to this module...

Comment: @inverted_index, the size of the embedded tensor is [32, 256], so I guess, I am missing the src_len dimension. Am I correct?

Comment: It does seem so. `self.rnn(...)` accepts the 3-d inputs where the first dim is the batch_size (32) that you're providing, the second for `seq_len` and the last for `embedding_dim`. You're missing on providing the `seq_len`. Changes should be made outside of the Encoder class. Considering that your `src` is a 2-d tensor of shape `[batch, seq_len]`, the `Encoder` class should be fine.